# ElasticSearch docker image on macos

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run the Elasticsearch image on my macos.  To that end I'm running the following commands as given on the site

`docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2`

followed by

`docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2`

However when I run this command I get the following error `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated` and it just crashes, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The exact command works on my MacOS. Please read the output, the exact error message should be in there. The one you are referring to is a warning, not an error so the process continues after that.

Comment: the container exits actually once you run this command and the status column has this `Exited (137) 8 seconds ago`

Answer (score 1):

It was a memory problem, I had allocated 2GB on my host machine, increased to 4GB and it worked fine now.